# Where are working dojox.storage AMD examples?

Tags: dojo

I can't seem to find dojox.storage documented somewhere recently. Is `dojox.storage` broken in **1.7 (AMD)?** It appears the unit-tests aren't even working. The example at `/dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dojox/storage/tests/test_storage.html` doesn't seem to work at all on FF or IE.

What is the recommended approach to using a local storage? In our case we'd like to use HTML5 storage that falls back on cookie storage when not available.

Comment: I'm using the dojox.storage.manager in 1.7.1 and it seems to work on HTML5 (local-storage) browsers, I haven't tested it on older (crappier) browsers. I'm not using full-AMD/async since the dojox.storage modules aren't AMD in 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/storage.html and http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14465, dojox.storage isn't expected to work with AMD and won't be for a while.

That said, this did work for me in dojo 1.8.3:

```javascript
require(["dojox/storage", "dojo/ready"], function (storage, ready) {
    ready(function() {
       var storageProvider = dojox.storage.manager.getProvider();
       storageProvider.initialize();
       var vals = storageProvider.get("InventoryMainSelectionHistory");
       var i = 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Below example from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/storage.html It's working on Dojo 1.7 and above.

```javascript
dojo.require("dojox.storage");
var storageProvider=null;
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
dojox.storage.manager.initialize();
storageProvider=dojox.storage.manager.getProvider();
storageProvider.initialize();
var myObject={key1:true};
storageProvider.put("myValue", myObject, function(status, keyName){
        alert("value put in "+keyName);
   });
});
```

Comment: Apparently this will be deprecated in 2.0

Answer (score 1):

As for **DoJo 1.9.2**, `dojox.storage` test (`/dojox/storage/tests/test_storage.html`) wasn't working. After nearer inspection it happened to be initialization issue in that particular code:

```javascript
// wait until the storage system is finished loading
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    // is the storage already loaded?
    if(dojox.storage.manager.isInitialized() == false){
        dojo.connect(dojox.storage.manager, "loaded", TestStorage, TestStorage.initialize);
    }else{
        dojo.connect(dojo, "loaded", TestStorage, TestStorage.initialize);
    }
});
```

The listener has registered waiting for event "loaded" on dojo, that wasn't called in newer DoJo version. After changing the code:

```javascript
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    TestStorage.initialize();
});
```

the example functions (for LocalStorageProvider) in both FireFox and IE 10.